# How to select multiple enum values from mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, enums

I have enum field Manufacturer

```
`manufacturer` ENUM('Manufacturer1','Manufacturer2','Manufacturer3','Manufacturer4') NOT NULL
```

and I have a array containing multiple manufacturer values. Ho to write query that would select every row that has, lets say for example, manufacturer1 or manufacturer3?

I could write it like this:

```
SELECT FROM table_name WHERE manufacturer=manufacturer1 OR manufacturer=manufacturer3;
```

but I am looking for shorter version like:

```
SELECT FROM table_name WHERE manufacturer=$myArrayOfManufaturers;
```

I get possible values of manufacturers form checklist so the number of manufacturers can change depending from user choice.

My site is built using CodeIgniter so I tried

```
    $query = $this->db->get_where('products', array('manufacturer' => $data['manufacturers']));
and using forech loop
foreach ($data['manufaturers'] as $man) {
            $this->db->or_where('manufacturer'=$man)
            }
```

but can not understand how to set first one as where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use IN query like

```
SELECT FROM table_name WHERE manufacturer IN ('Manufacturer1','Manufacturer2')
```